# Will renaming a `content.php` file cause any problems?

Tags: hierarchical, post-formats, template-hierarchy

I am currently creating a few templates for the various Blog formats, such as; 'Aside', 'Quote' and 'Gallery'.

I see a lot of people create such Templates by naming such files as:

- `content-aside.php`
- `content-quote.php`
- `content-gallery.php`

Has anyone experienced any problems in renaming these, using a different format?  For example:

- `format-aside.php`
- `format-quote.php`
- `format-gallery.php`

Also, would there be a problem in placing these in sub categories or is it best practice to keep these files in the top level of the Theme Directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There shouldnt be any issue, dont forget to change the slug in the template part call:

```
get_template_part( 'format', get_post_format() );
```

the best practice is to have them in their own folder:

```
get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/format', get_post_format() );
```

you can see the folder structure of `twentyseventeen` just change `content` respectively.

**How get_template will work**:

`get_template_part` will do a PHP require() for the first file that finds, it will create an array the first item array will use `slug` and `name` like this:

```
{$slug}-{$name}.php
```

the second item array will be:

```
{$slug}.php
```

the function will iterate the array of file names till it finds the one that exists.

so if you do a:

```
get_template_part( 'format', get_post_format() );
```

and for example the format is `video` the array of file names will be:

```
[0] "format-video.php"
[1] "format.php"
```

it will fallback to `format.php`, in the case of a `Child theme` the priority will be like this, with the `video` format as example:

```
[0] "format-video.php"  //in child theme
[1] "format-video.php"  //in parent theme
[2] "format.php" //in child theme
[3] "format.php" // in parent theme
```

Comment: I thought as much. I vaguely remember reading, some time ago, that 'content.php' file acted as a fall back file but couldn't find anything on Codex/WordPress Developers on the matter. Thanks for reaffirming my initial thoughts.

Comment: yeah it will, let me add info about it to the answer.